# sqlite transaction doesn't commit

Tags: python, sqlite

I run this code but it doesn't commit anything.

```
    def them_mon(self):
        ten_mon = ['Tin học', 'Toán', 'Nhạc', 'Mỹ thuật', 'Sinh', 'Lý', 'Văn', 'Thể dục', 'Sử', 'Địa', 'GDCD', 'TTH', 'AVTH', 'KHKT']
        len_tm = len(ten_mon)
        i = 0
        while i < len_tm:
            ten = ten_mon[i]
            #print(ten)
            sql = "INSERT INTO bang_diem(TEN_MON) VALUES(?)"
            self.conn.execute(sql, (ten,))
            i+=1
        self.conn.commit()
```

No record is added or anything in bang_diem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute with cursor object and not the connection object

```
# Creates or opens a DB
db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

# Get a cursor object
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabe_name (column1, column2) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (column1, column2))
db.commit()
```